Löb’s paradox in first-order logic
This excerpt is from Mendelson’s Introduction to Mathematical Logic:

I can think of two ways to reflect this formally. One uses bi-implication as a notion of “definitional equivalence”:

I tried to do the algebra and thought this concluded not B and A, but another answer I got is A and B.
The other way to do this is to use the entailment symbol. I think if we have entailment in two directions, we can say two formulae are logically equivalent:

I’m not sure I understand what the “paradox” is. Is it saying that for any collection of formulae, if a sentence of the form of B is included, then every other WFF follows? This would be the principle of explosion, if B is a contradiction / 0.
That wouldn’t be a paradox, since we don’t have to include B in a collection of formulae.

If you accept that B is a sentence that says that B implies A, then A is true. In particular if A = ⊥ you get a contradiction. There's nothing more to it. See Wikipedia. It's a paradox in the same sense as Russell's paradox: a seemingly innocuous logical principle ("it is always possible to construct a sentence B such that B means B → A") results in a contradiction. Thus we must restrict (negative) self-reference, just like ZF set theory restricts comprehension.

The paradox is more commonly known as Curry's paradox. It is considered by logicians to be of some significance in understanding the limitations of self-reference and definability. The article in the SEP has a pretty good explanation.

Well, we start with a sentence B that says: "If this sentence is true, then A is true" (where A is any other sentence).
The paradox arises when we try to reason about whether B is true or not:
If we assume B is true, then its own condition is met ("If this sentence is true..."), so A must be true.
But if A is true just because B said so, then B was correct in its claim, so B must be true.
This creates a circular logic where B's truth implies A's truth, which in turn confirms B's truth.
The paradoxical conclusion is that B is always true, and consequently, A is always true - regardless of what A actually says.
This seems to suggest that any sentence can be proven true just by constructing a sentence like B that refers to it.
It kinda challenges our intuitions about truth and self-reference in logical systems. Statements that refer to their own truth value can lead to unexpected and counterintuitive results.

Cool. I think I understand better now. The paradox is that in a formal system that permits the construction of that sentence, we are able to prove any statement, even ones established as false in that system. I learned that there is a formal proof/treatment which uses modal logic, which I’m going to study.

The flipside is that if we assume that "if this sentence is true, A is true" is false, and if we take the conditional to be material, then it follows that the antecedent is true, i.e. this sentence is true. So, whether we assume the sentence to be true or false, it entails the truth of B and A. Of course, this assumes that B is substitutable with B → A, which is dubious at best, and it assumes bivalence, which is debatable.

Here's me 2 cents...
B = B → A [Curry statement]
B → A ≡ ¬B ∨ A [Material implication]
So if we assume B we have:

¬B ∨ A  [Curry statement equivalent]
B [Assume]
¬¬B [2 DN]
A [1, 3 DS]

I see a resemblance with (ex contradictione sequitur quodlibet)...

B ∧ ¬B [Contradiction]
¬B [1 Simp]
¬B ∨ A [2 Add, Isn't this the Curry/Löb statement? Vide supra]
B [1 Simp]
¬¬B [4 DN]
A [3, 5 DS]

Spot the occult contradictione.
